# Python pptx - get the color of the text in a PPT?

Tags: python, powerpoint, rgb, python-pptx, textcolor

I want to get the color of the text for each text field in the PPT.

Is it possible to do with Python-pptx?

I'm trying using the below code to check if the text is green color and print Yes but it always prints No.

```
file = Presentation('file_name.pptx')
for slide in file.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if hasattr(shape, "text"):
            tf = shape.text_frame
            p = tf.paragraphs[0]
            if p.font.color == RGBColor(0, 255, 0):
                print("Yes")
            else:
                print("No")
```

Comment: Try if p.font.color.rgb == RGBColor(0, 255, 0):

Comment: @SteveRindsberg when I put p.font.color.rgb it's throughing as error **AttributeError: no .rgb property on color type '_NoneColor**

Comment: I'd guess, then, that Python-pptx doesn't support/expose that part of the PPT object model.